# ionic can't serve project (exit code 13)

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a beginner of ionic. I download repo and couldn't start it.(I try npm install) I getting an exit code 13. How can I solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your "npm install" output?along with you ionic version?

Comment: thank you for reply,  version is 6.6.0

removed 2 packages and audited 46355 packages in 6.486s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: output is;

removed 2 packages and audited 46355 packages in 6.486s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Can you send me repo url?

Comment: I can't share, company rules sorry. is it a code error or configure error?

Comment: Try running a blank project you will know.

Answer (score 1):

try command

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

and update python to the latest version 3.9.4

Answer (score 0):

Add a new script inside your package.json as lets say
`"start": "ionic serve --port=8080"`

Then run npm run start from the command line/terminal

what do you get?